# Equivalance classes example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's assume that we have equivalence relation ~ defined on interval $$[0,1]$$ such that $\{x\}$ $(0<x<1)$ and $\{0,1\}$ are the equivalence classes.

So $ [0] $ has two elements which are $0$ and $1$. But what about the second one? Does this mean that there is very large amount of equivalence classes that are based on singleton sets? Or are there just two equivalence classes?

This is very stupid question, I know, but I have lot's of these!

Comment: Is there a specific relation you are using to determine those equivalence classes? Or did you just choose them for the sake of example?

Comment: Just for the sake of example.

Comment: As you have written, the equivalence classes are infinitely many: all the singletons $\{ x\}$ for $x \neq 0,1$ (infinitely many, indexed by the interval $(0,1)$) and the last class $\{ 0,1 \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite understanding your notation so I will address both cases:

If, by $\{x\}$ $(0<x<1)$ you mean $\{x : 0<x<1\}$ then you have only two equivalence classes: one contained $0$ and $1$, and another containing all the real numbers between $0$ and $1$.

If, If, by $\{x\}$ $(0<x<1)$ you meant $\{x\} \forall x\in (0,1)$ then you have uncountably many equivalence classes. I think an example of this would be $x\sim y$ if $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$ (if their difference is an integer). $1-0=1$ and $0-1=-1$ are integers -- so they are in an equivalence class -- and the only other way to get integers from something in $0,1$ is by an element from itself ($.4-.4 =0$, an integer). That is, the equivalence class of some $x, \forall x\not \in \{0,1\}$ is $x$.

Comment: I'll add that this is part of an example written by our professor and the notation is confusing me. But, now by your second paragraph, I am pretty sure that he meant it. The subject is quotient spaces in elementary topology course.

Answer (score 0):

This way how you are taking the relation means that the two extremes of the interval are glued and the other are alone then the quotient set can be put into bijective correspondence with the unit circle via $\frac{[0,1]}{\sim} \to S^1$ defined by $t\mapsto (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$.

Comment: "This way how you are taking the relation means that the two extremes of the interval are glued and the other are alone " What this alone means? That they each are in their own equivalence class or they all are in one equivalence class?

Comment: both are in the same equivalence class, so each of them can represent it